# Strange collision behaviour in 2D game even though the collision is very basic

Tags: c#, 2d, collision-detection, unity

I have a player ship (cube) and some enemy laser projectiles. When the player ship has position X values greater than 1, collision with the enemy projectiles occur but when it has lower X values, the projectiles pass through.

If the image below is too small to view, you can refer to this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flf6P.png).

[image]

There are two screens in the image. The above image is where the collision occurs and the below one is where the laser projectiles miss the player ship. (You can see in a larger image better the tiles. When the collider of the player ship goes below the central horizontal line, collisions do not occur). Let me post the scripts for projectiles and player ship.

**LaserProjectile**

```
public class LazerProjScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private float speed = 5.5f;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        // translate
        transform.Translate (new Vector3 (0f, -1f, 0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // destroy the projectile once it's out of screen
        if(transform.position.y <= -10)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {

        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            print ("lazer on collision enter!");
            print ("hit player");
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>().hp -= 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") return;

    }

}
```

---

**Player Controller**

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int hp = 100;
    public float speed = 0.3f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        /*********************************************************/
        /********************** TRANSFORM CODE *******************/
        /*********************************************************/
        //horizontal <- || -horizontal ->
        //vertical down || -vertical up
        float h = -Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")*speed;
        float v = -Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")*speed;

        // do not let the ship get out of the camera
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") < 0 && transform.position.x <= -11.8) {
            h = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0 && transform.position.x >= 11.8) {
            h = 0;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") > 0 && transform.position.y >= 8.2) {
            v = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") < 0 && transform.position.y <= -8.2) {
            v = 0;
        }

        transform.Translate (h, v, 0);
    }
}
```

Please note that neither the player ship nor the laser projectiles are `isTrigger`, `isKinematic`. Both have their Z values 0 all the time when they translate.

I cannot identify the problem. If the collider is above X=1 axis, there's no problem. If it's below that, collision does not occur! What is this, how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

Well, I played with the positions a bit and it got stranger. If projectiles start moving towards the player when they are in some range, they collide but if they travel for a certain amount of time (i.e. if they are more distant than some distance) they do not collide. I changed the Y values of the projectiles and one collided with the player even though it was below the X=1, and the other just passed through.

**EDIT2**

If I do not move the player, the projectiles miss. When I *move* the player, collisions occur whatever the distance was.

Comment: Where is the method OnCollisionEnter called? Sorry I use answer for this but, I don't have enough rep to comment :-S

Comment: It's in the laserProjectile script, which is attached to the red laser projectiles. I mean, you can see the methods in the codes I posted so I believe you missed it. Otherwise, I do not get your question.

Comment: What is calling your "OnCollisionEnter" method?

Comment: Player doesn't have that method but the projectile has it. So laser projectile calls it ?

Comment: Are you sure your projectile is not "warping through" your player, i.e. at frame 1 it is at position 1, frame 2 it moves at position 7, but player was at position 3, thus not detecting the collision?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging code. Is there a way we could edit it to explain more about the problem and less about the technicalities of a solution?

Comment: @Anko I don't understand how this is off-topic. The Tour says ask about "game-specific programming issues (engine architecture, game-related APIs, networking, tools, etc)". This is a game-specific programming issue, isn't it? Can you tell me how exactly is this off-topic?

Comment: [Debugging questions](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/what-counts-as-a-debug-my-code-type-of-question) tend to involve lots of back-and-forth and to produce answers that aren't really useful to anyone but the asker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things suspect with your code:

1. You should not be calling `transform.Translate()` to move a projectile - it's possible that you'll translate it right over its target!

   Instead, attach a `rigidbody` component, turn off gravity, and set the velocity.  If the velocity is high enough, you may also need to set the collision mode to 'continuous'.
2. This code

   ```
   if(transform.position.y <= -10)
       Destroy(gameObject);
   ```

   is suspicious, since it relies on the absolute position to determine when an object is off-screen.

   Instead, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556496/21557543#21557543) for the proper way to determine if an object is off-screen.

Comment: I believe your answer misses the link for the 'this post'. Thanks for the answer, rigid body seems to solve it.

Comment: @Varaquilex Oops!  Try now.